# How to display different windows in different monitors with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, monitor, display

I have a PC with multiple monitors.

I want to display different windows in different monitor with OpenCV/C++.

How can I show the window in the specific window?

Thanks!

Comment: Maype this can help you with something: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24540091/opencv-fullscreen-windows-on-multiple-monitors]

Comment: @Skywrath Thanks for the reply! But I don't want to use with QT..
I was wondering if this can be done just by OpenCV. Now I'm going to display multiple images in an array, and each size is set as a monitor size.

Comment: Have you tried to use  http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#movewindow with (values ~= your screen resolution) for that? Wonder if will disappear or move to the other monitor. If the second is true - just find values which would suit you better. If it doesn't help - i guess you will need to use API provided by your OS to move window to different monitor.

Comment: @DmitriiZ. Yeah, after trying this ...it works!!! Thank you! =D

Comment: Nice to hear that, I've posted this as an answer :)

Comment: For debugging purpose I'd highly recommend using Image watch VS extension 


https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WolfKienzle.ImageWatch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [MoveWindow](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#movewindow) with (values ~= your screen resolution). Just find values which would suit you better, you can try using your [OS API to get values for screen resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690619/how-to-get-screen-resolution-in-c), or get this data from system variables